# Java Reversedigit check program

Tags: java

I've written a Reverse digit program but need to check this program to see if it is working correctly.  What am I missing an if/else statement?

```
import java.util.*;

public class IT145_Homework_7_3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // input int parameter
        System.out.print("Enter number to reverse: ");

        //sets variables 
        int original = scanner.nextInt();
        int reverse = 0;
        int remainder;

        //original number equals 542
        while (original != 0) {

            remainder = original % 10;  //2 //4  //5
            reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;  //2  //24  //245
            original = original / 10;  //54  //5  //0
        }
        //Prints out numbers in Reverse   
        System.out.println("Reverse of number is: " + reverse);
    }

}
```

Comment: First, what is the correct result for reversing `900`? `9` or `009`? Second, **what** `if-else` statement?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do the check, but you have to keep an int of the original before you change the original. I called it `originalInt`

```
// sets variables
int original = scanner.nextInt();
int originalInt = original; // Save it off here

// all of your code to run the reverse...

// Code to run the check...
String revStr = String.valueOf(reverse);
String orgStr = String.valueOf(originalInt);

// In case you are inputting negative ints
orgStr = orgStr.replace("-", "");
revStr = revStr.replace("-", "");

// remove all trailing zeros from original and check if they are equal
// This is for the cases where the input is '900' and your reverse is '9'
orgStr = orgStr.replaceAll("0*$", "");

boolean worked = true;

// if the lengths are equal, then check if the chars match in opposite directions.
if (revStr.length() == orgStr.length())
{
    int len = orgStr.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (orgStr.charAt(i) != revStr.charAt(len - (i+1)))
        {
            worked = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
else 
{
    worked = false;
}

System.out.println("Worked: " + worked);
```

**EDIT**: First code had bug.

Answer (score 0):

it can also be done as

```
int no=scanner.nextInt();
StringBuffer sb= new StringBuffer(no+"");
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(new String(sb.reverse())));
```

Comment: OP is not asking how to reverse an int, they are asking how to verify the algorithm.